# Floating point error in HSV conversion

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a function for converting vectors in RGB colorspace to HSV - the routine passes all tests and works the vast majority of the time. However, crash reporting indicates that it occasionally fails (0.0001% of calls or less.) But, since this function is called so much this accounts for a substantial portion of the total crashes in the software.

The relevant portion of the code is as follows:

```
glm::vec4 RGBtoHSV(glm::vec4 rgb)
{
    vec4 hsv = vec4(0,0,0,rgb.w);

    float r = rgb.x;
    float g = rgb.y;
    float b = rgb.z;
    float M = std::max(std::max(r,g),b);
    float m = std::min(std::min(r,g),b);
    float c = M - m;

    //calc hue
    float hp = 0;
    if (c == 0)
        hp = 0;
    else if (M == r)
        hp = glm::mod(((g-b)/c), 6.0f);
    else if (M == g)
        hp = ((b-r)/c) + 2;
    else if (M == b)
        hp = ((r-g)/c) + 4;
    else
        EXPECT(false);
    float h = hp * 60;

    ...
```

glm::vec4 is a reference to the [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/index.html) library, but the type is basically just this:

```
struct vec4 {
    union {
        struct { float x, y, z, w; }
        struct { float r, g, b, a; }
    }
}
```

The failing line is EXPECT(false); -- which is just asserting that we always reach one of the upper cases, and the question is how can control ever reach there?

Comment: Comparing floats for equality without epsilon is usually dangerous. However, `std::max()` should not modify `r`, `g` or `b`. So I guess, that at lease one of those is `NaN`, where a comparison always evaluates to false.

Comment: Good suggestion, that would definitely seem to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm somewhat perplexed and I'm considering deleting my answer because I can't reproduce this behaviour on my computer. This suggests somewhat to me that what is happening is implementation specific. Which compiler are you using and what floating point representation are you using?

Comment: I'm using Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79, based on LLVM 3.3svn) -- which is XCode 5.0.3, targeting armv7s and IEEE-754. I actually did get it to hit this condition, I just had to be sure that every value in the input vector was NaN

Comment: @Sam In the context of this code, your comment regarding the utility of an epsilon is nonsensical for a C++ compiler that defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` (inherited from C99 to C++03) to any positive value. While C++ specifies very little about floating-point arithmetic, in all likelihood, on any compiler that you will ever touch, both `M` and `m` are equal to one of `r`, `g` or `b`, and `c` is zero if and only if `r`, `g` and `b` are equal. Adding an epsilon anywhere into the mix would be utterly stupid.

Comment: That was a side note for those not aware of such pitfalls. No reason for your additional side notes. But maybe, I should work on my English skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that these are IEEE-754 floating point numbers then you might have a problem comparing with `NaN`. If you are using a different floating point representation then the rest of my answer might not be relevant.

It might sound a bit strange but **any** comparison with `NaN` returns False. So even if you are attempting to do `NaN == Nan` you get false. [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w22adx1s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you test for `NaN` in the part of your code where the assertion is raised then this is likely the problem. You can do this by using the `isnan()` found in `<cmath>` see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan.

I quickly put together some code to demonstrate, please let me know if the same happens on your system:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main(){
    float r = 0.0/0;
    std::cout << "r = " << r <<  std::endl;
    float g = 7.0;
    float b = 0.0;
    float M = std::max(std::max(r,g),b);
    float m = std::min(std::min(r,g),b);
    float c = M - m;

    //calc hue
    float hp = 0;
    if (c == 0)
        std::cout << "c == 0" << std::endl;
    else if (M == r)
        std::cout << "M == r" << std::endl;
    else if (M == g)
        std::cout << "M == g" << std::endl;
    else if (M == b)
        std::cout << "M == b" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "oops" << std::endl;
        if(std::isnan(M))
            std::cout << "NaN encountered" << std::endl;

}
```

On my machine compiling with gcc this gives the following output:

```
r = -nan
oops
NaN encountered
```

So it seems somewhat likely that there is a `0.0/0` going on somewhere else in the code.